# Visual Studio forces to start WP emulator on website debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-phone-7-emulator

I have VS solution which is mix of Websites, Console Application and Windows Phone Apps.

When I select my website as a start up project, in the device selection it only appears Windows Phone Emulator Devices not Debug selection.

So when I hit F5 emulator pops-up which I do not want unless I select WP project.

Is there any setting I can apply it will not show WP device if I just want to debug Website?

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio go to Build -> Configuration Manager, where all the projects in the solution will be listed. There is an option for the user to select which all projects needs to be selected for building and there you can select the only ones you need to build.

Comment: I already select Any CPU, there is no WP emulator listed, but still just next to green build button WP Emulator listed, could not change.